# Scrolling on Stack Overflow is slow if a question has lots of answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript, popups, performance

- Chrome Version: Google Chrome    70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- OS: Ubuntu

Try opening one of these pages:

- [How do I create a URL shortener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-do-i-create-a-url-shortener)
- [How to use a decimal range() step value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/how-to-use-a-decimal-range-step-value)

Scrolling is very laggy. I hit up the profiler and it shows me this:

[image]

This shows that scrolling triggers a lot of reflows. Further investigation suggests that this is coming from Popper.js somehow (bit hard to tell from the minified source though).

Comment: I have observed it on meta too, long/more answers sometimes create blank pages

Comment: I can reproduce frametimes around 80-95 ms on your first link with Chrome on Windows 10. The forced reflows certainly look unusual.

Comment: I confirm, scrolling through those pages is very laggy. Similar behaviour on *google chrome 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)*. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389212

Comment: Can you try a different browser? I see no lagginess in Firefox 69.0 (logged in to SO) or in Edge (not logged in) on Windows 10.

Comment: @Andrew Morton: Guessing it's a Chromium issue then. Blink!Edge reproduces this issue; EdgeHTML!Edge doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Indeed, Firefox 69.0 (64-bit) works fine for me too on Ubuntu.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389222/scrolling-performance-in-chrome-in-large-posts-suddenly-got-worse-over-the-past

Comment: This seems to be fixed now, at least I can't reproduce it anymore.

Comment: Yeah, fix was in at the tail end of last week; updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report! The root cause here was a script library we use to handle pop-ups combined with the presence of an invisible pop-up for every answer on the page.

Should now be fixed. Details: [Scrolling performance in Chrome in large posts suddenly got worse over the past week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389222/scrolling-performance-in-chrome-in-large-posts-suddenly-got-worse-over-the-past/389472#389472)