# Is scrolling on Anime and Wordbuilding slow as compared to sites with no background images?

Tags: bug, images, scrolling

I am using Safari 12.1.1 on macOS, with no extensions.

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com and https://anime.stackexchange.com seem to have a bit sluggish, inertial and non-smooth scrolling on their  home pages as compared to the sites with no background image in the sidebar, such as https://apple.stackexchange.com.

Is that true or is my system at fault?

> [image]

This screenshot was seen temporarily, but I do notice the sluggishness most probably due to the illustrations in the background.

**Debugging:**

The left part on the timeline is for Worldbuilding and right one for apple.

The blue marks are where I changed the web page.

Scrolled up and down a few times on per site.

[image]

[image]

This call tree screenshot is for Worldbuilding. I cannot find icon etc for export, thus the image.

[image]

For Apple

[image]

Comment: No repro in Chrome / Win 10.

Comment: We had [this bug earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333166/scrolling-on-stack-overflow-is-slow-if-a-question-has-lots-of-answers/333504#333504) but I don't think this is related.

Comment: Yeah I commented on that one too. All good on Firefox.

Comment: Would like hints towards creating reports on Safari. Currently trying to Find a JS profiler.

Comment: For Safari? Don't they no longer have the developer tools that come with Webkit?

Comment: Never used them. See the answer please. Might also want to move it into the question. Posted it below to keep discussion organised.

Comment: yeah, you better edit that in the question. Any change of having a call stack for those javascript events?

Comment: Call tree or Events? Also, If some safari user could tell me how to export those logs, I won't have to dig into https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Instruments/Instruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH4-SW1

Comment: I think call tree is most valuable as that should reveal if the start point is a SE script and which one it is.

Comment: Saw the answer below? I think that could fix it, if a developer looks here.. you think that's possible ?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363527/276692

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just diagnosed it and it's purely an issue with rendering background images in Safari and has nothing to do with Javascript. The slowdown occurs when using multiple images in `background-image` with *different* `background-attachment` attributes.

I made a bare-bones html file that shows the same slowdown in Safari but not Firefox and Chrome (and included the images in the same directory):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type=text/css>
      body {
        min-height: 200%;
        background-image: url("site-background-figures.png"), url("site-background-texture.png"), url("site-background-land.svg");
        background-position: top 90% left, top left, top left;
        background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat, no-repeat;
        background-size: 187px, 400px, 100%;
        background-attachment: fixed, scroll, scroll;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Changing the `background-attachment` section to:

```css
background-attachment: scroll, scroll, scroll;
```

or:

```css
background-attachment: fixed, fixed, fixed;
```

Fixes the slowdown in Safari because the images no longer need to be redrawn against each other constantly (I assume).

**Quick Fix:** Add a bookmark that points to: `javascript:$('body').css('background-attachment','scroll,scroll,scroll')` and click it to fix lag on the current site.

Comment: It would be nice if the worldbuilding css were changed to accommodate the bug, but it’s ultimately a problem with Safari and should be fixed there. I’ve submitted a Radar to Apple but who knows if we’ll see a fix any time soon :(

Comment: Could you explain how one adds a bookmark that 'points to' javascript:$('body').css('background-attachment','scroll,scroll,scroll') as you write it?

Comment: Add any generic bookmark with ⌘D, then right-click it in the bookmark bar and click "Edit Address...", then replace the address with the code.

Comment: Awesome! EDIT: It seems I have to (re)do it every time I load the site. Any way to get around that?

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to mention that but it's expected. You can find or make an extension to run it every time or rewrite the html with an adblock-type extension, but I don't have any recommendations.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response!