# worldbuilding.SE jittery scrolling on macOS Safari

Tags: bug, scrolling, page-rendering

For over 2 years worldbuilding.SE [still has this bug](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7003/9182) in macOS Safari where it (and no other site) has awful, choppy, laggy scrolling.

> it runs at a very choppy pace ... Scrolling on any page feels laggy and choppy to the extent that the site becomes hard to use

> choppy, laggy scrolling. It's very unpleasant to use

[Worldbuilding SE running slowly/choppy scrolling?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7003/9182)

> When scrolling down or up there is a noticeable frame-rate drop. What is intended to be smooth ends up been jerky

[The page background lags my laptop](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7980/9182)

Safari users have all managed to "fix" the issue through inspect element and disabling the `background-attachment` style rule on body. Unfortunately that causes the robot to not stick to its place in the bottom-left of the screen after scrolling down.

And also, perhaps like [this question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6810/9182) and [this question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6935/9182) where the askers were using Microsoft Edge, the background flickers and jumps around sometimes while scrolling. This is especially noticeable while scrolling fast or before the page has entirely loaded all content (like images).

Maybe, like Edge, Safari has a bug of its own that causes this behaviour. Why not float the robot as its own element instead of as a page background?

I hope this is fixed because it's finally aggravating enough to make me not want to browse that site anymore.

Comment: Page being jumpy before it is fully loaded is the case for all sites. It even causes you to not land on the answer your using the hyperlink for when there are a lot of images in the answers.